# Expressing set of sequences as one sequence

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

This is a discrete math problem, and i was hoping that someone will guide me in the right direction on how to go about solving it...

I have the following set of sequences:

a_(2n) = 8^n
This will give me the values of all the even terms

a_(2n+1) = (-3)8^n
This will give me the values of all the odd terms

I would like to know if there's a way for me to express the values of all terms (both even and odd) using only one formula! Would you please help me!

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as follows:

```
a_k=[-1+2*(-1)^k]*8^(floor(k/2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would you please help me understand your logic behind choosing to define it this way! Are you using (-1)^k to create an alternating effect, but why would you want to do something like the floor function?

Comment: In your definition, a_(2n) = 8^n. So you need to divide 2n by 2 to get n. However, in a_(2n+1) = (-3)8^n you want to do (2n+1)/2-0.5 to get n. So floor(k/2) takes care of both of them.

Comment: Thank you so much!